# 4th Modal Prevents NavBar Dropdown Menu From Functioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a Dropdown Menu in the NavBar & there are 4 Modals elsewhere on the page.
The Dropdown Menu stopped functioning after I added the 4th Modal for some reason.
If I remove the 4th modal, the Dropdown Menu work fine.
How can I make all 4 Modals & the Dropdown Menu work?
Any help is appreciated.

Link to a sample with the Modals working but not the dropdown menu: http://www.buzzpunchmedia.com/kuyaba/modals.html

Link to a sample with the 4th modal removed(mailing list btn) & the Dropdown Menu working: http://www.buzzpunchmedia.com/kuyaba/modals2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Restaurant</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
    .body-modal {
}
    </style>
    <link href="modals.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid" id="wrapper">
<div class="container-fluid" id="nav-container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
          <a class="navbar-brand menu-top" href="#">Menu <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-right"></span></a></div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li id="nav-home"><a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
              <li id="nav-rooms"><a href="rooms.html">Rooms</a></li>
              <li class="active active-text"><a href="restaurant.html">Restaurant</a></li>
              <li id="nav-bar"><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></li>

              <li class="dropdown" id="nav-more"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">More<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery/Tour</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">About/History</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gift Shop</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li id="nav-gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery/Tour</a></li>
              <li id="nav-about"><a href="#">About/History</a></li>
              <li id="nav-functions"><a href="#">Functions</a></li>
              <li id="nav-giftshop"><a href="#">Gift shop</a></li>
              <li class="nav-book" id="nav-book"><a href="reserve.html">RESERVE NOW</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    </div>
<div class="container main-background">
  <article id="main"><br>
<div class="row menu-buttons">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 breakfast-menu">
        <p> <a href="#breakfastModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary menu-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal">Breakfast Menu</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 lunch-menu">
        <p> <a href="#lunchModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary menu-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal">Lunch Menu</a> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <p> <a href="#dinnerModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary menu-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal">Dinner Menu</a> </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</article>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid footer-full">
      <div class="container footer-container">
<footer>
  <div class="row" id="footer-row">
<div class="col-sm-4 footer-rightcolumn">
<div class="footer-mailinglist"><p><a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-default maillist-btn" type="button" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></span> Join the Mailing List!</a></p></div>
  </div>

  </div>
<div class="row footer-links-row"> </div>


</footer>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>        


<!-- Begin E-Mail List Modal(MyModal) - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Join the E-Mail List</h4>
                </div><!-- end modal-header -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Receive info & updates about Specials, Coupons & Events.</p>
                            <hr>
                            <p><small class="text-muted">PS. Your info will be kept in strict confidence.</small></p>

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="http://www.fatcow.com/scripts/formemail.bml">
    <input type="hidden" name="my_email" value="john@somewhere.com" />
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Join the Mailing List" />
    <input type="hidden" name="required" value="fullname,emailaddress" />
           <div class="form-group">
           <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="fullname">Name</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="emailaddress">E-Mail</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="emailaddress" name="emailaddress" placeholder="you@somewhere.com">
        </div>
        </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
    <button class="btn btn-success pull-right" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Send!</button>     <button class="btn btn-default pull-right close-button" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="thankyou_url" value="http://www.buzzpunchmedia.com/kuyaba/index.html" />
    </form>
        </div><!-- end modal-body -->
            </div><!-- end modal-content -->
            </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- end myModal -->


<!-- Begin Breakfast Modal - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="breakfastModal">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Breakfast Menu</h4>
    </div><!-- end modal-header -->

<div class="modal-body modalimage-center"> <br>
<div class="modal-footer"><div class="col-lg-12">
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right close-button" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
</div>

        </div>
                                          </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                                      </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                                    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- end breakfast Modal -->


<!-- Begin Lunch Modal - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="lunchModal">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Lunch Menu</h4>
                                            </div><!-- end modal-header -->
                                            <div class="modal-body"> <br>
<div class="modal-footer"><div class="col-lg-12">
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right close-button" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
</div>

              </div>
                                            </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                                      </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                                    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- end Lunch Modal -->


  <!-- Begin Dinner Modal - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <div class="modal fade" id="dinnerModal">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                            <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Dinner Menu</h4>
                                            </div><!-- end modal-header -->
                                            <div class="modal-body"> <br>
<div class="modal-footer"><div class="col-lg-12">
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right close-button" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
</div>

              </div>
                                            </div><!-- end modal-body -->
                                      </div><!-- end modal-content -->
                                    </div><!-- end modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- end Dinner Modal -->


      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


@charset "UTF-8";
h1, h3, p {
    text-align: center;
}
.image-fill {
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
#main {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    font-size: medium;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
#nav-container {
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    box-shadow: 0px 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 8;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0 10px;
}
.menu-top {
    display: none;
}
.glyphicon.glyphicon-home {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#nav-home {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#nav-rooms {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#nav-restaurant {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#nav-bar {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#nav-more {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.active-text {
    font-size: 20px;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #CFF879;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav-book {
  background-color: #73a014;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(154,199,60,1.00) 0%, rgba(115,160,20,1.00) 86.53%);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(154,199,60,1.00) 0%, rgba(115,160,20,1.00) 86.53%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(154,199,60,1.00) 0%, rgba(115,160,20,1.00) 86.53%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(154,199,60,1.00) 0%, rgba(115,160,20,1.00) 86.53%);
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .nav-book > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .nav-book > a:focus {
  color: #cff879;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .nav-book > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .nav-book > a:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .nav-book.active > a,
.open .dropdown-toggle.nav-book {
  color: #73a014;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #cff879;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(157,219,29,1.00) 0%, rgba(207,248,121,1.00) 54.92%);
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(157,219,29,1.00) 0%, rgba(207,248,121,1.00) 54.92%);
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(157,219,29,1.00) 0%, rgba(207,248,121,1.00) 54.92%);
  background-image:         linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(157,219,29,1.00) 0%, rgba(207,248,121,1.00) 54.92%);
}

#nav-giftshop {
    display: none;
}
#nav-gallery {
    display: none;
}
#nav-functions {
    display: none;
}
#nav-about {
    display: none;  
}
.main-background {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.menu-buttons {
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.menu-btn, .menu-btn:focus {
    background-color: #73a014;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left-color: #73a014;
    border-right-color: #73a014;
    border-top-color: #73a014;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #464646;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #464646;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
}
.menu-btn:hover, .menu-btn:active, .menu-btn.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.menu-btn {
    background-color: #403C3C;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left-color: #73a014;
    border-right-color: #73a014;
    border-top-color: #73a014;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #464646;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #464646;
    outline: none;
 }

.footer-full {
    background-color: #403C3C;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -20px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset -20px 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 14;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.footer-container {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer-rightcolumn {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.footer-mailinglist {
}
.maillist-btn, .maillist-btn:focus {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left-color: #73a014;
    border-right-color: #73a014;
    border-top-color: #73a014;
    color: #73a014 !important;
    width: 78%;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #464646;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #464646;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
.maillist-btn:hover, .maillist-btn:active, .maillist-btn.active, .open .dropdown-toggle.maillist-btn {
    background-color: #73a014;
    font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-left-color: #73a014;
    border-right-color: #73a014;
    border-top-color: #73a014;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    width: 78%;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #464646;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #464646;
    outline: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
}

.modalimage-center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.image-center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.print-button {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.close-button {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: 2 things (and this is not an answer, but a very good tip) you don't need to call JQuery and Bootstrap.js so many times. You just need a reference once per document and make sure Jquery is above Bootstrap. And put them in the head. I know it is recommended to have scripts in the bottom, but these two are your heavy hitters.

Comment: Now, to the second thing. I copied your code in a codepen and it works fine for me. It is using a call to the latest jquery and bootstrap3. Perhaps, yours is tainted for some reason. Replace your code for the latest and use a real version of Jquery, not a latest.jquery.min. Here is the code to your working page http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMRgbL

Comment: Thanks so much LOTUSMS.
I really appreciate the tips & the answer to my problem.
It must have been something in the first modal that was corrupt. I changed it with your working code & all works fine now.
Again, Thank you.

Comment: I'm adding my response to the answer block so that others may see it. Your question is still showing unanswered.

Comment: How do I mark it as Answered?

Comment: There should be a answer checkmark that you click on. It's not visible to me, which is odd. The arrow up and down indicate whether you liked the answer or not. The checkmark validates the answer as the right asnwer to solve this problem

Comment: Apparently the checkmark is only visible to you. I never noticed that before

Comment: Thanks again. I clicked the checkmark. Kind of hard to see & no text indicating what it is.
I'm new & will remember next time.

Comment: Sure, no problem. It is always good to mark the answer when there is one. Others like yourself, come here and look for those green marks to help themselves. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the latest version of JQuery and Bootstrap in that specific order, preferibly in the head of the document. All other references to jqueries can go on the bottom.

Eliminate all the various calls to JQuery and Bootstrap before every modal.

```
<!-- Begin Dinner Modal - jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

DO NOT, under any circumstances alter Bootstrap.js. Use a separate main.js for all javascript functions.

After cleaning your code a little and using updated copies of JQuery and Bootstrap.js, it works fine.

Here is the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMRgbL) **code is too long to post here